# Error with "Creating new spfx listed view Command set extension" the command does not appear on Edge when debugging

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-extensions, browser-compatibility

I created a new SPFx listed View command set extension and change the URL in the serve.json file then debug it and got the following error (in the screenshot):
the problem here that the same link works on Firefox and chrome but not on Edge even after uploading the sppkg solution.

I have seen previous people has the same issue and suggested to delete the schema property in the "serve.json" file which did not work for me any other suggestion ?

[image: error when debugging]

Comment: would you mind to share your serve.json file?

Comment: Hi  @VeronaChen i added the serve.json file content as below please take a look at it maybe you have an idea of what is wrong going on thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

hi @VeronaChen thanks for your reply . the content of my serve.file file looks like the following :
i got a warning said that the property serveConfigurations not allowed here.[image: serve.json]